# Auto Import Signature in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin

Does anyone know of a way to automatically import a signature in Outlook? E.g. I can e-mail a signature as an attachment or part of the e-mail body and instruct some form of script to automatically import the signature for that e-mail account that received the e-mail.

For an IT nerd like me knows how to do this manually but my company would like to help those who feel the steps to create a signature are lengthy and easily forgettable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to manage signatures with either Group Policy or via a script. Take a look at this page:

Setting up a Corporate Signature | HowTo-Outlook
http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm[enter link description here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm)